# How do I print out 2 separate arrays with new lines in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So basically I want to be able to print out 2 separate arrays with newlines between each element.

Sample output I'm looking for:

```
a         x
b         y
```

(a,b being apart of one array x,y being a separate array)

Currently im using:

```
printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}        ${newWords[@]}"
```

But the output comes out like:

```
a
b         x
y
```

Comment: You can make a loop over one array and then print from first and second array in that loop. (This assumes both arrays have the same number of elements.) That said, questions here tend to get downvoted and closed if they look like you are just asking us to write code for you. Always add what you've already tried and how that didn't work. See [ask].

Comment: Please add output of `declare -p words newWords` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Assuming that the arrays have N elements each, you can make a counting loop from 0 to N-1 and in each iteration print the elements corresponding to the current index.

Answer (score 1):

As `bash` is tagged, you could use `paste` from GNU coreutils with each array as an input:

```sh
$ words=(a b)

$ newWords=(x y)

$ paste <(printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${newWords[@]}")
a   x
b   y
```

TAB is the default column separator but you can change it with option `-d`.

If you have array items that might contain newlines, you can switch to e.g. `NUL`-delimited strings by using the `-z` flag and producing each input using `printf '%s\0'`.

Comment: that does look closer to what i'm looking to achieve, but "x" didn't print out directly over y

Comment: @Feedolais With the sample array you provided, it does. If that sample does not represent your actual arrays well enough, follow @Cyrus' suggestion and provide the output of `declare -p words newWords` for more insight. If the "x didn't print out directly over y" because the actual items had too differing lengths, try looking into the `column` command from the util-linux package which takes care of the formatting of table-like structures.

Comment: Simple way to improve appearance of columns: pipe the output of `paste` into `| column -t`

Answer (score 1):

What does `"${words[@]}        ${newWords[@]}"` produce? Let's put that expansion into another array and see what's inside it:

```sh
words=(a b)
newWords=(x y)
tmp=("${words[@]}        ${newWords[@]}")
declare -p tmp
```

```sh
declare -a tmp=([0]="a" [1]="b        x" [2]="y")
```

So, the last element of the first array and the first element of the second array are joined as a string; the other elements remain individual.

---

`paste` with 2 process substitutions is a good way to solve this. If you want to do it in plain bash, iterate over the *indices* of the arrays:

```sh
for idx in "${!words[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "${words[idx]}" "${newWords[idx]}"
done
```